# Breaking the Strain Rate into normal and tangential components

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain, combustion

I was looking through a set of notes on combustion and I found this definition of the strain rate at a point on a flame surface:

$K_s = -\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf E \cdot \mathbf n $

where $ \mathbf n$ is the normal vector to the surface and $\mathbf E = \frac12 (\nabla\mathbf v + (\nabla\mathbf v)^T)$ is the rate of strain tensor. $\mathbf v$ is the velocity field.

According to the notes $K_s$ is also equal to

$K_s = -(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n) \kappa  + \nabla_t \cdot \mathbf v_t$

where the "t" subscript means "tangent" to the surface. $\kappa$ is the curvature of the surface. So the first term is the normal straining and the second term is the tangential straining.

How can I show that these two expressions are equal?  I've tried to do this by setting up curvilinear coordinates along the surface and then plugging and chugging, but it never quite works out.

The notes are found at:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjZ8I_A8e7gAhXmYN8KHbxWCuEQFjABegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcefrc.princeton.edu%2Fsites%2Fcefrc%2Ffiles%2FFiles%2F2011%2520Lecture%2520Notes%2FMatalon%2FLecture-8.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0CCg7pq0tWfu9ymTXqU1iJ
and the equations are on pg 3.